# How can I use a specific static template for subject,body in .net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using .NET MVC and currently I am working on a component that sends email to specific users. I have created the email functionality and I am able to send emails. But now, I am thinking to use a template sort of thing to make it better.

**my idea -**

There will be a file (in xml or text or anything) that will contain a specific template for an email structure as following -

> Subject: Welcome User "user (Passed from database)"
>
> Dear "UserName(Passed from database)",
>
> Welcome to the system.
> --more lines----
> --more lines----
>
> Regards,
>
> Admin

How can I achieve this using an external file. Suppose a config file or an XML or a text file. Any concept is welcome.

Comment: Define a file format; parse it to extract the separate fields when needed. Too many options for doing that (and too many tools to list to help). What is best will depend on the specifics your needs (eg. what format of email...) NB. [SO] isn't for tool recommendations.

Comment: I have used `strongly typed partial view` to generate template for email.

Comment: @mmushtaq ,Thank you for the suggestion. I will try it for sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have HTML template as

```
<strong>User Name: </strong> {UserName}<br />
 <strong>Email Id: </strong> {UserEmail}<br />
```

Now at controller you can use it like and replace the static values with that is being passed from front end or any source

```
public JsonResult FeedbackReply(MessageViewModel model)
        {        

           string emailBody = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Common/EmailTemplate/EmailTemplate.html"));
           emailBody = emailBody.Replace("{EmailId}", model.UserEmailId);
           emailBody = emailBody.Replace("{UserName}", model.UserName);  

           SendEmail.SendMailMessage(EmailSubjects.EmailReply, 
               emailBody, model.UserEmailId,
               ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CC"],
               ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CCName"]);

            return Json(new { status = true, message = CustomMessages.EmailSentSuccessfully }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

And here is the sendEmail class

```
 public class SendEmail
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Send email
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="subject"></param>
        /// <param name="body"></param>
        /// <param name="to"></param>
        /// <param name="cc"></param>
        /// <param name="ccName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool SendMailMessage(string subject, string body, string to, string cc, string ccName)
        {  
            using (MailMessage objMailMessage = new MailMessage())
            {
                using (SmtpClient objSmptp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        objMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
                        objMailMessage.Subject = subject;
                        objMailMessage.Body = body;
                        objMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                        objMailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailFrom"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailName"]);
                        objMailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cc) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ccName))
                        {
                            MailAddress objMailAddress = new MailAddress(cc, ccName);
                            objMailMessage.CC.Add(objMailAddress);
                        }
                        System.Net.NetworkCredential basicAuthenticationInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPUserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPPassword"]);
                        objSmptp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPHostName"];
                        objSmptp.Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);
                        objSmptp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                        objSmptp.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo;
                        objSmptp.EnableSsl = true;
                        objSmptp.Send(objMailMessage);
                        return true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        var exception = ex;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is what I wanted ... Thank you @Anil...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Razor (*.cshtml) templates.

Render

```cs
public static string RenderPartialView(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
        controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Usage

```cs
        EMail.SendEmail(
            from,
            to,
            sunj,
            this.RenderPartialView("MT_RestorePassword"));
```

Template "Views\Shared\MT_RestorePassword.cshtml"

```cs
@{
    ViewBag.Title = S.RestoringPassword;
}

<h2>@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ASE.SiteName"] - 
@S.RestoringPassword</h2>
<hr />
<h3><b>@S.User: </b> @ViewBag.User</h3>
<h3><b>@S.RestorePasswordCode: </b> @ViewBag.Code</h3>
```